# Terraform: referencing each.key or each.value in module when calling variables

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to achieve (maybe by wrong means) something like that. I'd like to be able to create few types of endpoints in Azure (KV, SA for example).

```
module "endpoints" {
  source = "./modules/private_endpoint"

  for_each = toset(var.endpoint_type)

  private_connection_resource_id  = "var.${each.value}.private_connection_resource_id"
```

Where:
Endpoint_type is a list of endpoints (its value is "storage_account"),
private_connection_resource_id   is in map(any) which looks like (there are other values, but I don't think they're important at this point):

```
storage_account = {
    private_connection_resource_id = #VALUE
...
```

private_connection_resource_id  = "var.${each.value}.private_connection_resource_id" --- this gets translated to literal string (var.storage_account.private_connection_resource_id), where I'd like it to get translated to exact value - the id of storage account (it's hardcoded in tfvars).

Thank you in advance for any tips!

Edit: It appears that Im as dumb as they come. Should've changed the map a bit:

```
endpoint_type = {
  storage_account = {
    private_connection_resource_id = #VALUE
...
```

And ref in module calling to: each.value.private_connection_resource_id

Comment: That will not work. It would be better to use the same keys in the variable `private_connection_resource_id` instead of naming the variable based on the key values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot construct an expression inside a string and then evaluate it. Terraform always parses the full configuration *first* and then executes it once already parsed.

If you want to look up values dynamically based on a key then a map is the most appropriate data structure to use for that purpose. For example, you could define a input variables `endpoint_types` and `endpoints` like this:

```
variable "endpoint_types" {
  type = map(object({
    private_connection_resource_id = string
  }})
}

variable "endpoints" {
  type = map(object({
    type = string
  }))
}
```

My intent with the above example is that the `type` attribute inside the `endpoints` objects is a lookup key for the other map in `endpoint_types`.

When you then define your `module` block with `for_each` you will first refer to `var.endpoints` and then look up an appropriate endpoint type in `var.endpoint_types` based on its selected key:

```
module "endpoints" {
  source   = "./modules/private_endpoint"
  for_each = var.endpoints

  private_connection_resource_id = var.endpoint_types[each.value.type].private_connection_resource_id
}
```

The user of the outer module would need to provide both a map of endpoints and a map describing all of the possible types those endpoints might have, like this:

```
endpoints = {
  storage_1 = {
    type = "storage"
  }
  storage_2 = {
    type = "storage"
  }
  other_1 = {
    type = "other"
  }
}
endpoint_types = {
  storage = {
    private_connection_resource_id = "something"
  }
  other = {
    private_connection_resource_id = "something_else"
  }
}
```